Optimizing Column Selection for Row-Wise Minimum Sum in Matrices
I have an issue finding an efficient solution for the following problem:
Given a rectangular matrix of integers with dimensions ×, select exactly  columns and then, for each row in the matrix, choose a single element from the selected columns such that the total sum of the chosen elements is minimized.
Example:
Input:
 = 2 (You must select 2 columns)

Matrix:
[4 2 7]
[3 8 1]
[5 6 9]

Output: Selecting columns {1,2} gives the smallest total sum of 9.
I have tried progressively constructing combinations of columns from smaller to larger subsets. Starting with individual columns, I build combinations by adding one column at a time, ensuring that every combination of size  is eventually generated.
For each combination, I compute the row-wise minimum of the selected columns and sum these values across all rows. To avoid redundant computations, I store intermediate results for smaller combinations and use them when building larger combinations.
My issue with this is it's computationaly expensive for larger matrices and I'm looking for suggestions for more efficient solution if such solution exists.

Why the output of the example is 9? If we choose columns 1, 2, we will pick 3 from column 1 and pick 2 from column 2, hence getting a minimal answer 5.

@Sayakiss I believe what OP is trying to say is that you must choose one number for each row, and it must come from a chosen column. For the provided example, choosing {1, 2} (0 indexed) lets you choose 2 from the first row, 1 from the second, and 6 from the third, which is indeed the best you can do.

@HerbertTheBirdthat is correct. Thank you for clarification.

Funny that exactly on the same date that you ask this question an article about the topic is published on Dev Code F1 ...

@Markus I'm not avare of the same problem being metioned elsewhere as this is something I've encountered during developement of my own project. Have they provided a fast solution? Can you post a link to the article?

See https://devcodef1.com/news/1429154/column-selection-with-minimum-sum-matrices. Beware of clickbait!

Not sure if it adresses exactly your point or something similar.

Also please consider to ask questions like this on https://math.stackexchange.com/.

I have an answer to this, which will be implemented in Python. But I probably can't get to it until Monday. @Markus, I consider this one a wobbler. It is a math problem. But anyone sane would want to turn that math into a computer program, so it is also a programming problem. And there are tricks to that conversion.

@Markus thank you for the link. It's even formulated the same way, that's weird.

Maybe you can say the range that things are going to be, if this is not going to be general(additional heuristic optimisation if values vary so much/ m*n is very high like 10000)

@redoc I'm curous if there is asymptotically better solution, but it looks like paralelised bruteforce will have to do. The matricies for which I need to calculate this are average around 10 columns and 100 - 500 rows.
For heuristics - after discussing this with my colleague he suggested prefering columns with frequent minima, though I haven't figured out when to stop searching yet.

I can do a greedy approximation really easily. The full solution requires some clever ideas. It is not always guaranteed efficient, but it is an A* search that usually does well. That will take another couple of days, and will be more of a proof of concept than an efficient solution.

My apologies, but I got sidetracked by a lot of life, and a long time frustration that Python doesn't seem to have any good libraries for providing https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure. And that is absolutely what I want to have. I'm guessing that that takes me 2 weeks to build a prototype, which means it is more likely a month. Sorry. But the short answer is, "Try all the things, with an A* algorithm. Just make switching between different starts cheap."
